# Using react, get username from ID inside child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am sorry if this has been asked before... I searched but could not find a solution. Anyways...

I have successfully mapped out data from my API.

In my `HomePage.js` component I have the following:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchOrdersAction());
}
```

...

```
{orders.data.length > 0 &&
    <div className="order-items d-flex flex-row align-items-stretch flex-wrap">
        {orders.data.map((list, index) =>
            <ListOrderItem order={list} key={index} clickHandler={this.handleListCardClick} />
        )}
    </div>
}
```

Inside my `ListOrderItem.js` my render looks something like:

```
render() {
    const { order, user} = this.props;

    return (
        <div className="order-item d-flex justify-content-between" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <span className="name-data-holder">{order.user_id}</span>
            <span className="date-data-holder"><Moment date={order.created_at} format="MM/DD/YYYY"/></span>
            <span className="product-name-data-holder">id: {order.product_id}</span>
            <span className="price-data-holder">${order.amount}</span>
            <span className="actions-data-holder">
                <p className="sm-red-action-btn">View Order</p>
            </span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

For now, I am returning `{order.user_id}` which works as intended. What I am trying to do now is get the user's first name that is associated with that ID.

My idea was to create a dispatch like:

```
this.props.dispatch(fetchUsersAction(`filter[id]=5`));
```

I added this to `HomePage.js`

If I view my network tab I can see that the dispatch is successful and is returning the data for user 5.

What I am struggling with is the following:

1. Getting this to run in each instance of `listOrderItem`
2. Dynamically passing the user ID to the filter

I tried running the dispatch inside `ListOrderItem` but I get an error similar to *functions are not valid as a react child*

A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can dispatch from ListOrderItem.js in the componentWillMount() function

```
componentWillMount() {
   const {order} = this.props
   this.props.dispatch(fetchUsersAction(`filter[id]=${order.user_id}`));
}
```

But that sound like a lot of api calls in a list.
Can you just insert them in the response directly from your api?

Comment: That worked in helping get the ID dynamic, thanks so much.

I guess you're right about a large number of calls. I guess the better way to approach this would be to pull the user's first name when the record is created via the API?

Comment: Yes i guess or just join  the users table in the query for orders